ComboBox - add user value to dropdown list
I have CComboBox - dropdown type. I add there any predefined values from my own list in OnInitDilaog()  method.
User can either choose value from list or add his own value to editbox. How can I add new user value to droplist? Ideally when he press Enter?
 BOOL CMFCtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
   {
       m_cCombo.AddString(L"Volba 1");
       m_cCombo.AddString(L"Volba 2");

       return TRUE;  
   }


Is the dialog a popup window? This may cause strange UI behavior, as the [Enter] by default is captured by the dialog's default button, usually the IDOK button, which closes the dialog. In MFC this happens even if your dialog doesn't actually have a default button (calls the OnOK() member), and you have to write some code to prevent this. If you want to capture [Enter] if the combo box's edit control is focused, this is possible, but pls take into account the considerations above.

A better design may be to simply get rid of the edit box and instead add a pre-defined item like "Add a Value" to the list, and if the user selects it then prompt them for a value and add it to the list.

The problem with the Win32 Combo-Box is that it doesn't automatically add the edit-box contents to the list, neither it sends some notification when the  Enter key is pressed. So we have to capture the key event, that is process the its messages. In MFC we can use the PreTranslateMessage() function. It's often used as a "last resort" solution, but in this case it comes in really handy. The handle of the edit-box can be obtained by calling the Win32/MFC GetComboBoxInfo() function (or sending the CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO message).
Take the following steps:
In the dialog class add a HWND member to hold the handle of the edit-box:
private:
    HWND hWCBEdit = NULL; // Combo-box's edit-control

Add some few code lines in the dialog's OnInitDialog() member:
BOOL CMFCtestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    // Do not delete this, it binds member variables to controls, among others!
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Get and store CB's edit-control
    COMBOBOXINFO cbi { sizeof(COMBOBOXINFO) };
    m_cCombo.GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);
    hWCBEdit = cbi.hwndItem;

    m_cCombo.AddString(L"Volba 1");
    m_cCombo.AddString(L"Volba 2");

    return TRUE;
}

Override the dialog's PreTranslateMessage() member as shown below:
BOOL CMFCtestDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // Capture [Enter] key for the CB Edit-Box
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->hwnd == hWCBEdit && pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN)
    {
        TCHAR sCBEdit[100];
        if (::GetWindowText(hWCBEdit, sCBEdit, 100) > 0) // CB Edit-Box non-empty
        {
            if (m_cCombo.FindStringExact(-1, sCBEdit) < 0) // String not in the drop-list
                m_cCombo.AddString(sCBEdit);
            // Maybe Add some more actions here
        }
        return TRUE; // Message processed, no further processing is needed
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}

This adds the edit-control contents to the list if the Enter key is pressed. The dialog will NOT close if Enter is pressed while the edit-control is focused.
An alternative solution, not using PreTranslateMessage(), could be to subclass the edit-control. This is done by changing its window procedure (check if Enter was pressed, otherwise call the original one).

IIRC, you do not need to go so low level to do these things. If you put DLGC_WANTALLKEYS on the combobox's properties and process it with a OnKeyDown  / OnKeyPress / OnKeyUp , or if this does not, you can make it work with a GetDlgCode , and achieve the same result. @IInspectable
